# How to make a line break on the Python ternary operator?

Tags: python, line-breaks

Sometimes a line containing a ternary operator in Python gets too long:

```
answer = 'Ten for that? You must be mad!' if does_not_haggle(brian) else "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel."
```

Is there a recommended way to make a line break at 79 characters with a ternary operator? I did not find it in [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Comment: Put it in parentheses.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can always extend a [logical line across multiple physical lines](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#line-structure) with parentheses:

```
answer = (
    'Ten for that? You must be mad!' if does_not_haggle(brian)
    else "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel.")
```

This is called [implicit line joining](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#implicit-line-joining).

The above uses the PEP8 everything-indented-one-step-more style (called a [hanging indent](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#indentation)). You can also indent extra lines to match the opening parenthesis:

```
answer = ('Ten for that? You must be mad!' if does_not_haggle(brian)
          else "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel.")
```

but this leaves you hitting the 80-column maximum all the faster.

Where precisely you put the `if` and `else` portions is up to you; I used my personal preference above, but there is no specific style for the operator that anyone agrees on, yet.

Answer (score 55):

PEP8 says the [preferred way of breaking long lines is using parentheses](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#maximum-line-length):

> The preferred way of wrapping long lines is by using Python's implied
>   line continuation inside parentheses, brackets and braces. Long lines
>   can be broken over multiple lines by wrapping expressions in
>   parentheses. These should be used in preference to using a backslash
>   for line continuation.

```
answer = ('Ten for that? You must be mad!'
          if does_not_haggle(brian)
          else "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel.")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I find the two answers equivalent so I accepted the older one.

Comment: Upvoting for monty python reference

Comment: @Mark The Python quote was in the original question.

Answer (score 13):

Bear in mind this advice from *The Zen of Python*:
"Readability counts."

The ternary operator is most readable when it is all on one line.

`x = y if z else w`

When your conditions or variables push the line past 79 characters (see PEP8), readability begins to suffer. (Readability is also why dict/list comprehensions are best kept short.)

So, rather than trying to break the line using parentheses, you might find it is more readable if you convert it to a regular `if` block.

```
if does_not_haggle(brian):
    answer = 'Ten for that? You must be mad!'
else:
    answer = "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel."
```

BONUS: The above refactoring reveals another readability issue: `does_not_haggle` is inverted logic. This would be even more readable, if you can rewrite the function:

```
if haggles(brian):
    answer = "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel."
else:
    answer = 'Ten for that? You must be mad!'
```

Comment: That is not more readable after one gets a bit accustomed to seeing a variable declared in one place: you do not show the *declaration* of `answer` - which requires yet *another* line. This is bloat.

Comment: @javadba no other declaration of `answer` is needed. Both branches include a declaration.

Comment: @PeterWood That is true.  So only half of my comment applies.

Comment: mutability, mutability, all is mutability

Comment: I also find that when it's about declaring a var, it's clearer to have it once, and not in branches.

Answer (score -1):

Just like that:

```
if does_not_haggle(brian): answer = 'Ten for that? You must be mad!'
else: "It's worth ten if it's worth a shekel."
```